# Angular2 CanActivate undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to add some restriced routes in my app. I write a Guard like they are explained in the docs here but i try to achieve it without typescript: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards

My Guard look like this but i can not use CanActivate because it is not defined in `@angular/router` v3.1.1

```
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './app.auth.service';

console.log(CanActivate); // undefined

export class AuthGuard extends CanActivate {
  constructor(AuthService) {
    super();
    this._authService  = AuthService;
  }

  canActivate() {
      return this.checkIfLoggedIn();
  }

  _checkIfLoggedIn() {
      const user = this._authService.getUser();

      return user;
  }

  static get parameters() {
    return [[AuthService]];
  }
}
```

Any Ideas?

**EDIT**

This approach works as expected, thanks @PierreDuc for help me back on the track.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './app.auth.service';

export class AuthGuard  {
  constructor(AuthService, Router) {
    this._authService = AuthService;
    this._router = Router;
  }

  canActivate() {
    if (this._authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      return true;
    }

    this._router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }

  static get parameters() {
    return [[AuthService], [Router]];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it's an `interface`. This is only used in type hinting and static typing within `TypeScript`. It has no actual output in the compiled `JavaScript`. For that reason it will logically evaluate to `undefined`.

A reason your code might not be working is because you use `checkIfLoggedIn` and define a function with `_checkIfLoggedIn` (the **`_`** is missing in the call).

Another reason could be that `getUser` is an async function. In that case you should return a `Observable<boolean>` or a `Promise<boolean>`

Comment: Ok, thank you. Interface is the keyword. Interfaces are not part of the ES6, right?! You have an idea how to use the guard/canActive concept with es6 and without TypeScript?

Comment: @d-bro82 it's not necessary to extend it to enable to guards any ways, The same way it works in TypeScript it should work in ES6 as well.

Comment: Got It! This was very helpful, ty